# Get sum of the value from list using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, list, c#-3.0

I am trying to get the sum of the value from list of list using linq ?my data is as below code

```
        List<List<string>> allData = new List<List<string>>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                List<string> dataList;
                dataList = reader.ReadLine().Split('|').ToList();
                allData.Add(dataList);
            }
        }
```

which gives me data in `allData` as below

```
           allData-->[0]-->[0]-'name1'
                           [1]-'sub'
                           [2]-'12'
                     [1]-->[0]-'name2'
                           [1]-'sub'
                           [2]-'15'  
                     [2]-->[0]-'name1'
                           [1]-'sub2'
                           [2]-'15'
    //and so on ....
```

i have applied group by that gives me grouping by the name but i am not able to figure out how to get the sum of the marks for each name ?

```
      var grouped = allData.GroupBy(x => x[0]);
```

after this i get all matching name grouped into one but now how to get sum of the marks for that group ? any help would be great ?

```
  Output should be  name1=27 and name2=15 and so on.
```

Comment: Is the number to be added always the third element of each list?

Comment: @BrianSnow Yes it will always be third element

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var grouped = allData.GroupBy(x => x[0])
                     .Select(g => new
                     {
                         Name = g.Key,
                         Sum = g.Sum(x => int.Parse(x[2]))
                     });
```

It will return an anonymous type instance for each group, with two properties: `Name` with your grouping key and `Sum` with sum of marks.

Answer (score 29):

Not sure if you want to get the sum of every group or the total.  If it's the total then this should do the trick

```
var sum = allData.Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x[2]));
```

If it's per key then try the following

```
var all = allData
  .GroupBy(x => x[0])
  .Select(x => x.Sum(y => Int32.Parse(y[2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sticking as much as possible to the `LINQ` query language:

```
var grouped = from d in allData
              group d by i[0] into g
              select new
              {
                  Name = g.Key,
                  Sum = g.Sum(i => int.Parse(i[2]))
              };
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you parallel List with each name and the count of how many times each name occurs.

```
    var names = grouped.Select(s => s.Key).ToList();
    var nameCount = grouped.Select(s => s.Count()).ToList();
```

Also... you may want to add this when assigning alldata to grouped. I use this to get a List from greatest to least amount of occurrences.

```
    var grouped = allData.GroupBy(x => x[0]).OrderByDescending(i => i.Count());
```

Comment: i dont want the name count if you look at the question i want the sum of third element from inner list.

Comment: oh, sorry. I was confused by the "Output" line..... it says "Output should be  name1-27 and name=15 and so on..." --> should it be: "Output should be  name1 = 27 and name2 = 15 and so on..."..... Either way I learned something new, that was a unique question and those are some great solutions to your problem!